# How to create a kdb rest api

Tags: api, rest, curl, kdb

I am looking to create a rest api in kdb+ / q. Let's say my data is coming from some function `.ns.func`. Currently, I have something like:

```
.ns.zphOrig:.z.ph;
.ns.zphWrapper:{[zph; x]
   if[(x 0) like "*getData*"; :.h.hy[`json] .j.j .ns.func[x]];
   ret zph;
   ret}
.z.ph:.ns.zphWrapper[.ns.zphOrig];
```

With this, if I go to my page, let's say at "http://localhost.com:6789?getData&name=rob" then I will get the data in the correct json format. However, when I try to connect any other way, KDB seems to not see there was a request made at all and I get a 401 error.

I have also tried the following, still getting a 401 error with no sign of traffic.

```
.z.ws:{[x] neg[.z.w] .j.j .ns.func[x]}
```

When this is done, I will then connect to a C# program. Also, I cannot use any external libraries and I am using version 3.6. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Some questions: 1. what is `ret` and what does it do? 2. You've modified the http handler `.z.ph` so naturally it only handles http calls. What other ways did you try to connect? If you connected using IPC then it wouldn't have gone through `.z.ph` it would go through the `.z.pg` handler. 3. `.z.ws` will handle websocket flow but that requires a little more setup (documented on code.kx.com)

Comment: Thanks for this! Was trying to create a basic REST API as a proxy and this helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having was rooted in permissioning. The actual api was working fine once I cleared that up.